# Android: Providerinstaller module and updating security provider

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am checking id the security provider is installed by calling

```
 ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync
```

I wanted to test the case where update fails. So I had the device offline so that it will not be able to update the security provider. But I see these logs

> com.xxx.debug W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller
> module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote
> version is 0.
> 2020-07-15 16:11:07.244 10334-10435/com.xxx.debug
> I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider
> GmsCore_OpenSSL

What does these logs mean.
I see these logs every time installIfNeededAsync is called, which makes me think that there is no actual install happening.

I see that onProviderInstalled callback is getting called which means the services is updated. But then why should these logs come every time?
Is there a way to test the scenario where the provider is outdated.

Comment: So which of the `ProviderInstallListener` methods was called?

Comment: How can i get to know that. I am not sure about that. I see only this in the logs

Comment: Implement a `ProviderInstallListener` and pass it to `installIfNeededAsync`.

Comment: Ah you mean the callback? Its always calling the success one. override fun onProviderInstalled() { } is getting called